# Alter multiple column comments simultaneously in spark/delta lake

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

**Short version**: Need a faster/better way to update many column comments at once in spark/databricks. I have a pyspark notebook that can do this sequentially across many tables, but if I call it from multiple tasks they take so long waiting on a hive connection that I get timeout failures.

Command used: `ALTER TABLE my_db_name.my_table_name CHANGE my_column COMMENT "new comment"` ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/2.x/spark-sql/language-manual/alter-table-or-view.html#change-columns))

**Long version**: I have a data dictionary notebook where I maintain column descriptions that are reused across multiple tables. If I run the notebook directly it successfully populates all my database table and column comments by issuing the above command sequentially for every column across all tables (and the corresponding table description command once).

I'm trying to move this to a by-table call. In the databricks tasks that populate the tables I have a check to see if the output table exist. If not it's created, and at the end I call the dictionary notebook (using [`dbutils.notebook.run("Data Dictionary Creation", 600, {"db": output_db, "update_table": output_table})`](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#api) to populate the comments for that particular table. If this happens simultaneously for multiple tables however the notebook calls now timeout, as most of the tasks spend a lot of time `waiting for client connection with hive`. This is true even though there's only one call of the notebook per table.

**Solution Attempts:**

1. I tried many variations of the above command to update all column comments in one call per table, but it's either impossible or my syntax is wrong.
2. It's unclear to me how to avoid the timeout issues (I've doubled timeout to 10 minutes and it still fails, while the original notebook takes much less time than that to run across all tables!). I need to wait for completion before continuing to the next task (or I'd spawn it as a process).

**Update:** I think what's happening here is that the above Alter command is being called in a loop, and when I schedule a job this loop is being distributed and called in parallel. What I may actually need is a way to call it, or a function in it, without letting the loop be distributed. Is there a way to force sequential execution for a single function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found a solution for this issue.

First, the problem seems to have been that the loop with the `ALTER` command was getting parallelized by spark, and thus firing multiple (conflicting) commands simultaneously on the same table.

The answer to this was two-fold:

1. Add a `.coalesce(1)` to the end of the function I was calling with the `ALTER` line. This limits the function to sequential execution.
2. Return a newly-created empty dataframe from the function to avoid coalesce-based errors.

Part 2 seems to have been necessary because this command is I think meant to get a result back for aggregation. I couldn't find a way to make it work without that (`.repartition(1)` had the same issue), so in the end I returned `spark.createDataFrame([ (1, "foo")],["id", "label"])` from the function and things then worked.

This gets me to my desired end goal of working through all the alter commands without conflict errors.

It's clunky as hell though; still love improvements or alternative approaches if anyone has one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change multiple columns at once, why not recreate the table? (This trick will work only if table 'B' is an external table.  Here table 'B' is the 'B'ad table with outdated comments. Table 'A' is the good table with good comments.)

1. drop table ('B')
2. create table with required comments ( 'A' )

If this table is NOT external, then you might want to [create a view](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-view.html), and start using that.  This would enable you to add updated comments without altering the original tables data.

Have you considered [using table properties](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-tblproperties.html) instead of comments?

Comment: In this case I'm creating the table automatically based on a streaming dataframe. I then alter the comments to add them for any columns I have in my dictionary. That way new columns of data show up even if I haven't had a chance to add comments to them yet. Point being, I can't drop the table because it has data in it. Also, adding comments to the table is needed because subsequent processes carry those comments to child tables.

Comment: If the table is 'external' if you drop the table and no data is lost.  (It doesn't delete the data, it's a feature of external tables.)

Comment: LIke I said, if the table is NOT extenal, then I suggest using a view, as this will enable you to slap on new definitions without touching the original table. (Views are just constructs to make life easier, and are often forgotten about.)

Comment: The view thing has given me trouble in the past because I'm trying to base a streaming dataframe off it for subsequent processes, which generally gives me errors saying views aren't yet supported for streaming. Otherwise I'd be doing a lot more of that already.

Comment: Also, these are all managed tables, so I don't think the external option would work, would it?

Comment: I updated my answer to include table properites that might be a good workaround.

Comment: That covers me for adding a description to the table itself, which I do once per table, but not for adding comments to the columns. There are specific reasons I want to do that.

Comment: Also note that dropping a table may drop table access permissions depending on how you have implemented those (e.g. in Databricks SQL).